# Multiple circles -> One Polygon?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bezier, geometry

Using Google Maps API v3, I was able to create multiple `google.maps.Circle` objects on my map. However, I now need to "connect" them somehow. I have the following map with multiple circles:

[image: Map with multiple circles]

I now need to get it to look something like this:

[image: Correct map]
<sub>(source: [pcwp.com](http://www.pcwp.com/images2009/ui-2.gif))</sub>

I've looked all over the Internet for solutions, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, I would be interested in seeing how this turns out, if you have the possibility to link to what you're doing.

Answer (score 8):

You may want to consider tackling this problem by adding addional circles at `x` intervals with increasing radiuses between each point of the path. This would be very easy to implement and will work for any direction of the cyclone. Obviously [Matti's suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614591/multiple-circles-one-polygon/2614614#2614614) to create a polygon by connecting all the tangents would be more accurate, but you can consider this as an possible alternative. The main downside is that it may require some effort to make it look pretty, and it will obviously use more client-side resources than if you were to render a single polygon.

Let's start by recreating your map:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps Cyclones</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var i;

      var mapOptions = { 
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.50, -81.50),
         zoom: 5
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), 
                                    mapOptions);

      var pathPoints = [
         new google.maps.LatLng(25.48, -71.26),
         new google.maps.LatLng(25.38, -73.70),
         new google.maps.LatLng(25.28, -77.00),
         new google.maps.LatLng(25.24, -80.11),
         new google.maps.LatLng(25.94, -82.71),
         new google.maps.LatLng(27.70, -87.14)
      ];

      pathPoints[0].radius = 80;
      pathPoints[1].radius = 100;
      pathPoints[2].radius = 200;
      pathPoints[3].radius = 300;
      pathPoints[4].radius = 350;
      pathPoints[5].radius = 550;

      new google.maps.Polyline({
         path: pathPoints,
         strokeColor: '#00FF00',
         strokeOpacity: 1.0,
         strokeWeight: 3,
         map: map
      });

      for (i = 0; i < pathPoints.length; i++) {
         new google.maps.Circle({
            center: pathPoints[i],
            radius: pathPoints[i].radius * 1000,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 1, 
            map: map
         });
      }

   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

[Google Maps Cyclones - Figure 1 http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/1197/mp1h.png](http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/1197/mp1h.png)

I assume that you heave already arrived to this point, and therefore the above example should be self-explanatory. Basically we have just defined 6 points, along with 6 radiuses, and we have rendered the circles on the map, together with the green path.

Before we continue, we need to define a few methods to be able to calculate the distance and the bearing from one point to another. We will also need a method that will return the destination point when given a bearing and the distance travelled from a source point. Fortunately, there is a very good JavaScript implementation for these methods by Chris Veness at [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). The following methods have been adapted to work with Google's `google.maps.LatLng`:

```
Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
   return this * Math.PI / 180;
}

Number.prototype.toDeg = function() {
   return this * 180 / Math.PI;
}

google.maps.LatLng.prototype.destinationPoint = function(brng, dist) {
   dist = dist / 6371;  
   brng = brng.toRad();  
   var lat1 = this.lat().toRad(), lon1 = this.lng().toRad();

   var lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(dist) + 
                         Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(dist)*Math.cos(brng) );
   var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(dist)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                               Math.cos(dist)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));

   if (isNaN(lat2) || isNaN(lon2)) return null;
   return new google.maps.LatLng(lat2.toDeg(), lon2.toDeg());
}

google.maps.LatLng.prototype.bearingTo = function(point) {
   var lat1 = this.lat().toRad(), lat2 = point.lat().toRad();
   var dLon = (point.lng()-this.lng()).toRad();

   var y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
   var x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) -
           Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon);

   var brng = Math.atan2(y, x);

   return ((brng.toDeg()+360) % 360);
}

google.maps.LatLng.prototype.distanceTo = function(point) {
   var lat1 = this.lat().toRad(), lon1 = this.lng().toRad();
   var lat2 = point.lat().toRad(), lon2 = point.lng().toRad();
   var dLat = lat2 - lat1;
   var dLon = lon2 - lon1;

   var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
           Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * 
           Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);

   return 6371 * (2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)));
}
```

We would then need to add another loop that renders the intermediate circles inside the `for` loop that we used previously to render the original circles. Here is how it can be implemented:

```
var distanceStep = 50;    // Render an intermediate circle every 50km.

for (i = 0; i < pathPoints.length; i++) {
   new google.maps.Circle({
      center: pathPoints[i],
      radius: pathPoints[i].radius * 1000,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.2,
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeWeight: 1, 
      map: map
   });

   if (i < (pathPoints.length - 1)) {
      distanceToNextPoint = pathPoints[i].distanceTo(pathPoints[i + 1]);
      bearingToNextPoint = pathPoints[i].bearingTo(pathPoints[i + 1]);
      radius = pathPoints[i].radius;
      radiusIncrement = (pathPoints[i + 1].radius - radius) / 
                        (distanceToNextPoint / distanceStep);

      for (j = distanceStep; 
           j < distanceToNextPoint; 
           j += distanceStep, radius += radiusIncrement) {

         new google.maps.Circle({
            center: pathPoints[i].destinationPoint(bearingToNextPoint, j),
            radius: radius * 1000,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            strokeWeight: 0,
            map: map
         });
      }
   }
}
```

This is what we would get:

[image: Google Maps Cyclones - Figure 2]

And this is how it would look without the black stroke around the original circles:

[Google Maps Cyclones - Figure 3 http://img181.imageshack.us/img181/2908/mp3t.png](http://img181.imageshack.us/img181/2908/mp3t.png)

As you may notice, the main challenge will be to render the circles with a consistent opacity, even when they overlap on each other. There are a few options to achieve this, but that could be the topic of another question.

In any case, the following is the full implementation for this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps Cyclones</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
      Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
         return this * Math.PI / 180;
      }

      Number.prototype.toDeg = function() {
         return this * 180 / Math.PI;
      }

      google.maps.LatLng.prototype.destinationPoint = function(brng, dist) {
         dist = dist / 6371;  
         brng = brng.toRad();  
         var lat1 = this.lat().toRad(), lon1 = this.lng().toRad();

         var lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(dist) + 
                               Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(dist)*Math.cos(brng) );
         var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(dist)*Math.cos(lat1), 
                                     Math.cos(dist)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));

         if (isNaN(lat2) || isNaN(lon2)) return null;
         return new google.maps.LatLng(lat2.toDeg(), lon2.toDeg());
      }

      google.maps.LatLng.prototype.bearingTo = function(point) {
         var lat1 = this.lat().toRad(), lat2 = point.lat().toRad();
         var dLon = (point.lng()-this.lng()).toRad();

         var y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2);
         var x = Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) -
                 Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2)*Math.cos(dLon);

         var brng = Math.atan2(y, x);

         return ((brng.toDeg()+360) % 360);
      }

      google.maps.LatLng.prototype.distanceTo = function(point) {
         var lat1 = this.lat().toRad(), lon1 = this.lng().toRad();
         var lat2 = point.lat().toRad(), lon2 = point.lng().toRad();
         var dLat = lat2 - lat1;
         var dLon = lon2 - lon1;

         var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                 Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * 
                 Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);

         return 6371 * (2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)));
      }

      var i;
      var j;
      var distanceToNextPoint;
      var bearingToNextPoint;      
      var radius;
      var radiusIncrement;
      var distanceStep = 50;    // Render an intermediate circle every 50km.

      var mapOptions = { 
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.50, -81.50),
         zoom: 5
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

      var pathPoints = [
         new google.maps.LatLng(25.48, -71.26),
         new google.maps.LatLng(25.38, -73.70),
         new google.maps.LatLng(25.28, -77.00),
         new google.maps.LatLng(25.24, -80.11),
         new google.maps.LatLng(25.94, -82.71),
         new google.maps.LatLng(27.70, -87.14)
      ];

      pathPoints[0].radius = 80;
      pathPoints[1].radius = 100;
      pathPoints[2].radius = 200;
      pathPoints[3].radius = 300;
      pathPoints[4].radius = 350;
      pathPoints[5].radius = 550;

      new google.maps.Polyline({
         path: pathPoints,
         strokeColor: '#00FF00',
         strokeOpacity: 1.0,
         strokeWeight: 3,
         map: map
      });

      for (i = 0; i < pathPoints.length; i++) {
         new google.maps.Circle({
            center: pathPoints[i],
            radius: pathPoints[i].radius * 1000,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 0, 
            map: map
         });

         if (i < (pathPoints.length - 1)) {
            distanceToNextPoint = pathPoints[i].distanceTo(pathPoints[i + 1]);
            bearingToNextPoint = pathPoints[i].bearingTo(pathPoints[i + 1]);
            radius = pathPoints[i].radius;
            radiusIncrement = (pathPoints[i + 1].radius - radius) / 
                              (distanceToNextPoint / distanceStep);

            for (j = distanceStep; 
                 j < distanceToNextPoint; 
                 j += distanceStep, radius += radiusIncrement) {

               new google.maps.Circle({
                  center: pathPoints[i].destinationPoint(bearingToNextPoint, j),
                  radius: radius * 1000,
                  fillColor: '#FF0000',
                  fillOpacity: 0.2,
                  strokeWeight: 0,
                  map: map
               });
            }
         }
      }

   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Whoa, nice answer. I'll have to try and implement mine too, so I can post some code (will be good exercise for my rusty geometry skills)

Comment: @Matti: I'm looking forward to see your attempt :) ... To be honest, I was going to try to implement your tangets approach first, but the math was getting a bit too tricky at 2.00am!... Feel free to reuse any part from the code of my answer, if you really decide to take the plunge.

Comment: Keep in mind that at each of the six individual circles there is a forecast error. Unfortunately, I only know the forecast error at these points, so it would have to be an average along those additional 50km circles.

Answer (score 4):

If it's always a string of circles along a line, you could process a pair of adjacent circles at a time, find the two lines that are tangents to both of them and connect them up by their intersections to make one contiguous path. Add some interpolated bezier control points for smoothness.

This might break if your string of circles isn't as neat as the one in your first post (lots of overlap, circles inside circles, etc), but it's a start.

Comment: Sometimes there could be circles moving from east to west, sometimes north to south, and sometimes the circles could be very close if the cyclone is not moving very fast during the forecast period. There could also be times where there is a very well-defined recurvature, where it would almost be in a C-pattern. Would this still work? If so, I'll get started on it!

Comment: It should work. If you get into trouble with too many circles, you can always discard some.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that there will be times where there are no intersecting lines, so it would be impossible to find them (see the first image)

Comment: I'm not talking about the intersections of the circles themselves, but their tangents.

Comment: @Matti: I didn't even notice that it told you how to find it actually. I just linked to it as an example of what you were talking about. Hopefully I didn't spoil his fun too much :-)

Comment: @Matthew: Well, I guess it doesn't spoil too much.